# Add a WebAPI OData $orderby option in an ODataController

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I've written a OData WebAPI controller inherting from [`ODataController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.odatacontroller%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

```
public class ManyColumnsController : ODataController
{
    [Queryable(
        AllowedOrderByProperties = "Aa,Bb,Cc,Dd",
        EnsureStableOrdering = false,
        MaxOrderByNodeCount = 2)]
    public IQueryable<ManyColumn> GetManyColumns(
            ODataQueryOptions<ManyColumn> options)
    {
        // Because I've disabled EnsureStableOrdering,
        // I need to check column "Dd" is always included
        // in the OrderBy option.
        if (!options.OrderBy.RawValue.Contains("Dd")
        {
            // I need to add an OrderByPropertyNode to
            // options.OrderBy.OrderByNodes. 
        }

        return this.context.ManyColumns;
    }
}
```

How can I instantiate an [`OrderByNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.orderbypropertynode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) to add to the generic collection exposed by [`OrderByQueryOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.orderbyqueryoption%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)?

---

You'll note that one constructor of [`OrderByNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.orderbypropertynode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) takes an [`IEdmProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.edm.iedmproperty%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). I feel there should me some trivial way to find an instance of [`IEdmProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.edm.iedmproperty%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) from the [`IEdmModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.edm.iedmmodel%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) exposed at [`options.Context.Model`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.odataquerycontext.model%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) and the [`IEdmType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.edm.iedmtype%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) at [`options.Context.ElementType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.odataquerycontext.elementtype%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

If this is achievable, I could use the instance in place of the string search in the `if` statement. In addition to adding it to the whole `OrderByClause`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEdmEntityType entityType=options.Context.ElementType as Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmEntityType;
IEdmStructuralProperty property = entityType.DeclaredStructuralProperties().Single(p => p.Name == "Dd");
IEdmType edmType=property.Type.Definition;
```

Comment: This does directly answer my question. However, the code compiles and runs but, adding a node doesn't seem to effect the `Order By` that is generated :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can get the property just as Jinfu said,

but I think you can new an OrderByQueryOption and call ApplyTo to meet your requirement.

```
var result = this.context.ManyColumns;
if (!options.OrderBy.RawValue.Contains("Dd")
{
    var orderBy = new OrderByQueryOption("Dd", new ODataQueryContext(Request.GetEdmModel(), typeof(ManyColumn)));
    result = orderBy.ApplyTo(result );
}
```

Comment: This is close I think, but if `$orderby` options are specified in the request, they override the applied `ORDER BY`, later in the pipeline.

Comment: Maybe you can combine the original $orderby raw value with "Dd" to your customized $orderby rawvalue in the order you want with the orderby properties. The $orderby raw value can be split by comma.

Comment: Makes sense but, it has no setter.

Comment: Oh you are right. What about applying other query options in the ODataQueryOptions and then applying your customized orderby query option.

Comment: Another reasonable idea but, the options seem to have a level of immutability. The `ORDER BY` is replaced with the original options, even if I call `options.OrderBy.OrderByNodes.Clear()`.